# Hide attributes/Class name

Tags: r

It is known that we can add a class "fun" on `abc` using

```
class(abc) <- append(class(abc), "fun")
```

After that `abc` will give us:

```
> abc <- matrix(1:4, nr=2)
> class(abc) <- append(class(abc), "fun")
> abc
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
attr(,"class")
[1] "matrix" "fun"
```

Is there a way to append the class "fun" to `abc` but not showing

```
attr(,"class")
[1] "matrix" "fun"
```

To be clear, the following is what I get:

```
> abc <- list(1:4, letters[1:3])
> abc
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

> class(abc) <- append(class(abc), "fun")
> abc
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

attr(,"class")
[1] "list" "fun" 
> class(abc)
[1] "list" "fun"
```

But I want:

```
> abc <- list(1:4, letters[1:3])
> abc
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

> class(abc) <- append(class(abc), "fun")
> abc
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

> class(abc)
[1] "list" "fun"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `print()` method for your class.

```
print.fun <- function(x) {
    class(x) <- Filter(function(x) x!="fun", class(x))
    print(x)
}
```

Note that because you are appending your custom class to the end of the class list, if another print method is found for an earlier value in the list, that one will be used instead.